# how vi automatically collapses {}

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I always come across a lot of code wrapped in {}s while reading, and I wondered if there was a way for vi to automatically fold these {}s instead of manually marking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set this value:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

Comment: I open a file with "vi", and enter "set foldmethod=syntax" which works well. But if I add "set foldmethod=syntax" to the vimrc, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I thought you're using vim not vi. I don't even have the option 'foldmethod'. Anyway according to the man page of vi, you should put `set foldmethod=syntax` into your `$HOME/.exrc` file if you're using `vi`.

Comment: I don't think OP's issue comes from the fact they are using vi (they probably have aliased 'vi' to 'vim' like in most distributions today). The issue is that if you read [`:h 'foldmethod'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldmethod%27) you'll see that this option is local to a window, so setting it up in the `.vimrc` doesn't affect the other windows. One will need to either use an autocommand (e.g. [`:h BufReadPost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufReadPost)) or a ftplugin [`:h ftplugin-overrule`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule).